# why is std::chrono::duration based on seconds

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

I'm learning `<chrono>` library, and considering the `std::chrono::duration` class, is there any specific reason to base it on seconds? For example a variable to store seconds would be

```
chrono::duration<int> two_seconds(2);
```

and all other time spans require relating them to seconds, like

```
chrono::duration<int, ratio<60>> two_minutes(2);
chrono::duration<int, ratio<1, 1000>> two_milliseconds(2);
chrono::duration<int, ratio<60 * 60 * 24>> two_days(2);
```

Are there any reasons to base duration on seconds and not on minutes, hours, etc.?

Comment: Seconds are the physical base for time duration values. May be this is the reason?

Comment: If it had been any other unit, would you have asked the corresponding question?

Comment: It must be based on *something*, since it is stored as an integral value and a ratio (of integrals). What else would you suggest as the base unit? Seconds is the most natural, as it is the [SI unit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units#Base_units) for time.

Comment: If it was to be passed as a template parameter, how would these types be defined? I guess by using a ratio to some base unit. And this is exactly what `chrono::duration` does by itself. You can also use milliseconds as your "base" if you use the type `std::chrono::milliseconds` (which is typedefed to what you already posted in your second line of code)

Comment: _"any reason ... not on minutes, hours, etc.?"_ Thanks to [leap seconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second), minutes and hours don't have a consistent duration.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Seconds are chosen because it's the basic time unit in both the SI system and in science as a whole.
Even Americans use seconds and not something like microfortnights.

> why this basic time span isn't another template parameter for duration class

It is, as you can provide `typedef`s for ratios, and some are included in the standard.

```
#include <chrono>

std::chrono::duration<int, minutes> two_minutes(2);            // Standard
std::chrono::duration<int, milliseconds> two_milliseconds(2);  // Standard
```

If you need more, they're trivial to add:

```
typedef std::ratio<60 * 60 * 24> days;
typedef std::ratio<756, 625> microfortnights;

std::chrono::duration<int, days> two_days(2); 
std::chrono::duration<int, microfortnights> two_weeks(1000000);
```

Comment: "Even Americans use seconds and not something like microfortnights." +1 for that :)

Comment: The standard already includes things like `std::chrono::milliseconds`. See the section labelled "Helper Types" on [this page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration).

Comment: @Steve Oops, I should have checked and not taken OP's word for it.

Comment: It is never too early to start preparing for the first of April... `using microfortnights = duration<long, std::ratio<756,625>>;` ;-)

Comment: @HowardHinnant there is Duff's rule that says that pi seconds is a nanocentury

Comment: @TemplateRex:  3944619/1250000 == 3.1556952 seconds.  Not bad! :-)